# Tiny MCE v2.1 code editor

Tags: download, attributes, tinymce

Call me old fashioned, but there is nothing I can do but only to use the old version of Tiny MCE, which is 2.1.

So, what I'm trying to do is to add a "download" attribute to  tag, after I open HTML editor I type this attribute, when saving it simply disappears. There is no official documentation to this old version on the official site. The new ones doesn't mention anything about this feature at all. [overall editor look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amokQ.jpg) [code editor look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONFd4.jpg)

Also, I tried to add "download" in the extended valid elements configuration:
extended_valid_elements: "code[class|dir ,however no success as well.

Did anyone by any chance faced the same problem?
Could use a little bit of help.

Comment: trying to add a "download" attribute to "<a>" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone ever encounters the same problem, which I highly doubt, you would need to open tiny_mce.js file, and on the line 1928 there will be "A : "id|class|style|title|download" ", this is the place, where I added "download". Afterwards I was able to add this attribute in the HTML code editor.